# Servlet WebSocket Acessed by Android

Tags: android, servlets, websocket

I'm trying learn how to use the websocket and make a simple servlet for being connected with Android but I don't get it.

The index.jsp :

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/myws/ServletWS");
ws.onopen = function()  { }; 
ws.onclose = function() { }; 
ws.onerror = function() { log("ERROR"); }; 
ws.onmessage = function(data) { var message = data.data; }; 
function sendMessage(msg) { ws.send(msg); }
```

How or where I receive the data from client?

Now on the servlet:

```
@Override protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String subProtocol, HttpServletRequest request) {
  return new ConnectionWS();
}

class ConnectionWS extends MessageInbound {
  private WsOutbound outbound;
  @Override protected void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) { 
    this.outbound = outbound; 
  }
  @Override protected void onTextMessage(CharBuffer msg) throws IOException {
    String message = msg.toString();
    ServletWS.processData(message);
  }
  public void sendMessage(String message) {
    CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.wrap(message);
    try {
      outbound.writeTextMessage(cb);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
  }
}

public void processData(String message){
    here I have to call the sendMessage with the answer to the client
}
```

I have saw a lot of examples on web but all of then about chat.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that, you have a basic knowledge about tomcat configuration as well as java Servlet programming. As WekSocket is newly introduced in Tomcat, you may need to use latest tomcat version to implement WebSocket over it. I have used Apache Tomcat 7.0.42 for it.

So here we go. First, create a Servlet which will just create a new WebSocket for the request.  You may need to modify it, if you want to go by session rather than request. Here is sample code.

```
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.StreamInbound;
import org.apache.catalina.websocket.WebSocketServlet;

public class WsChatServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1456546233L;

    @Override
    protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String protocol,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new IncomingMessageHandler();
    }
}
```

Now, create a Message Handler class which will handle each WebSocket stream independently. and that's it !

```
public class IncomingMessageHandler extends MessageInbound {

    private WsOutbound myoutbound;
    public IncomingMessageHandler() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) {
        logger.info("Open Client.");
        this.myoutbound = outbound;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int status) {
        logger.info("Close Client.");           
    }

    /**
     * Called when received plain Text Message
     */
    @Override
    public void onTextMessage(CharBuffer cb) throws IOException {

    }

    /**
     * We can use this method to pass image binary data, eventually !
     */
    @Override
    public void onBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer bb) throws IOException {

    }

    public synchronized void sendTextMessage(String message) {
        try {
            CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(message);
            this.getMyoutbound().writeTextMessage(buffer);
            this.getMyoutbound().flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {   
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set websocket connection timeout in milliseconds,
     * -1 means never
     */
    @Override
    public int getReadTimeout() {
        return -1;
    }

    public WsOutbound getMyoutbound() {
        return myoutbound;
    }
    public void setMyoutbound(WsOutbound myoutbound) {
        this.myoutbound = myoutbound;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If not misunderstood and you want to use web sockets on Android then recommended API for you is `jWebSocket`.

**Get it here**, hopefully it already provides you APIs for a lot of the work that you need to do or even more.

http://jwebsocket.org/

Comment: Ok, but I think the problem is not the Android, for first I'm using Autobahn framework on Android.

Comment: Thanks, MasterJ can I use the jwebsocket only in Android? Because now my servlet is working good. I have another questions, like how to send a messsage for only one client and not for everybody, on the examples every then teachs how to broadcast. And the other question is how to disconnect because even if I close the connection by the framework, the servlet don't activate the onDisconnect, in other words the function don't print the message disconnected.

Comment: I think you can do these things using this API. For this, you only need to explore it little more and do some handling on your end. Please accept the answer if it is useful.